# Excel Formula SUMIF by typing year

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My Excel file has *sheet1* and *sheet2*, in *sheet1* I have A1 to A999 for dates and B1 to B999 for sales figure for that date in a row.

In *sheet2* I have A1 to A12 for months like Jan, Feb, Mar...Dec and I am trying to calculate the total from *sheet1* dates and totals, the formula should check how much total is for the month which should be displayed in sheet2 B1 to B12 based on months.

In sheet1 A1 to A999 I have dates from different years so I am trying to have a C1 in sheet2 where I will type year 2018 or 2017 then the table should display the total for that year.

Comment: Your suggestion is not based on the requirements. Please review again and give the formula if you can. Thanks

Comment: You don't include a tag for formula. In fact you put vba. Setting it up this way is more efficient and when you add new rows to the table you only have to refresh the pivot for everything to update. You don't need to create new formulas etc. Also, no typing in a year, you simply select from the drop down. And whilst your title refers to SUMIF this remains a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Set sheet1 up as an excel table with an additional columns for year and for month (you can use Year and Month functions if you have a proper data format in column A) and create a pivottable off that and place it in sheet 2. Then put your Year in the page field and your month in the row field and your sales go in the values area.

Year formula in C2

```
=YEAR(A2)
```

Month Name formula in D2

```
=TEXT(A2,"mmmm")
```

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

You can create a table by selecting a cell in your data range e.g. `A2` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

You then create a pivottable with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

And place that in sheet 2

Pivottable layout in sheet 2

[image: Pivottable]

You can then use the page filter (year) to get the sum by month for each year

[image: Year filter]

If you want to be sure of MonthName order you can either drag into right order or have another column in sheet1 which, say in E2, says

```
=MONTH([@Date])
```

This will return the month number of the date and you can put this in the row fields and use it to order the months (e.g. in ascending fashion)

Ordering ascending with month number:

[image: Month number]

Comment: I managed to add two columns in sheet1 but how do i add the formula in sheet2

Comment: Can you attach this file you created please? Thanks

Comment: https://ufile.io/zupfj  here you go. No formulas in sheet2. You simply create the pivot and when it asks you were to put it, you specify sheet2. You can do insert > pivottable or Alt + N + V when in the table area in sheet 1.